# how to get keys or values data from a json column

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

trying to get data from `json` column - as described [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/)
table name - arts
column name - tops
example of content:

```
{"what": "video", "title": "antonio"}
```

query inside `phpmyadmin 5.02`:

```
SELECT tops->'$.title' tops FROM arts;
```

result - syntax error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$.title' tops FROM arts LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`

any help

from phpmyadmin:
`Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407`

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c179bd173d8152b47caf7f2fc197ba5d

Comment: or did you get [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c179bd173d8152b47caf7f2fc197ba5d) syntax error ?  (Please specify which version of MySQL you are using, and the EXACT error message)

Comment: Maybe you have PHP issue? For example, you wrap the query text as a literal with single quotes and does not quote inner quote chars? Or you wrap it with dquotes and does not quote dollar sign?

Comment: I suspect you need to upgrade your version of MySQL.

Comment: @Luuk - see my update, pls

Comment: @Akina - there is no php code here. query is inside phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your **MariaDB** server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$.title' tops FROM arts LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Your DBMS is MariaDB, not MySQL...

Use `JSON_EXTRACT()` instead of `->`:

```
SELECT tops, JSON_EXTRACT(tops, '$.title') title FROM arts;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7e83d5309a74a861f59171b426315142)